# Dynamic table JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I already have php code written all right, through Ajax requests go. when I click on edit, it appears in the input line, I enter the data, they are sent to the server, but this input is not deleted. The row of the table should return to the initial state, but already with the changed data. The same problem with deleting a row, when you click on delete, data is deleted from the database, but nothing happens in the frontend.
Link with code https://codepen.io/alekspvn/pen/EwwwrZ    sorry for php code here)
if there is unreadable, then I input the code here

HTML

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="10" border="1" id="user_table">
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Anonce</th>
<th>Url</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php
 foreach($eq_arr as $row):
 ?> 

  <tr id="row<?php echo $row->id;?>">
  <td id="title_val<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->title;?></td>
  <td id="anonce_val<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->anonce;?></td>
  <td id="url_val<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->url;?></td>
  <td>
   <input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button<?php echo $row->id;?>" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
   <input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button<?php echo $row->id;?>" value="save" onclick="save_row('<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
   <input type='button' class="delete_button" id="delete_button<?php echo $row->id;?>" value="delete" onclick="delete_row('<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
endforeach;
?>

<tr id="new_row">
 <td><input type="text" id="new_title"></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="new_anonce"></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="new_url"></td>
 <td><input type="button" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row();"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

JS

```
function edit_row(id)
{
 var title=document.getElementById("title_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var anonce=document.getElementById("anonce_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var url=document.getElementById("url_val"+id).innerHTML;

 document.getElementById("title_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='title_text"+id+"' value='"+title+"'>";
 document.getElementById("anonce_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='anonce_text"+id+"' value='"+anonce+"'>";
 document.getElementById("url_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='url_text"+id+"' value='"+url+"'>";

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="block";
}

function save_row(id)
{
 var title=document.getElementById("title_text"+id).value;
 var anonce=document.getElementById("anonce_text"+id).value;
 var url=document.getElementById("url_text"+id).value;

 jQuery.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'../wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/update.php',
  data:{
   edit_row:'edit_row',
   row_id:id,
   title_val:title,
   anonce_val:anonce,
   url_val:url
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    document.getElementById("title_val"+id).innerHTML=title;
    document.getElementById("anonce_val"+id).innerHTML=anonce;
    document.getElementById("url_val"+id).innerHTML=url;
    document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="none";
   }
  }
 });
}

function delete_row(id)
{
 jQuery.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'../wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/update.php',
  data:{
   delete_row:'delete_row',
   row_id:id,
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
   }
  }
 });
}

function insert_row()
{
 var title=document.getElementById("new_title").value;
 var anonce=document.getElementById("new_anonce").value;
 var url=document.getElementById("new_url").value;

 jQuery.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'../wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/update.php',
  data:{
   insert_row:'insert_row',
   title_val:title,
   anonce_val:anonce,
   url_val:url
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response!="")
   {
    var id=response;
    var table=document.getElementById("user_table");
    var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
    var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+id+"'><td id='title_val"+id+"'>"+title+"</td><td id='anonce_val"+id+"'>"+anonce+"</td><td id='url_val"+id+"'>"+url+"</td><td><input type='button' class='edit_button' id='edit_button"+id+"' value='edit' onclick='edit_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='save_button' id='save_button"+id+"' value='save' onclick='save_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='delete_button' id='delete_button"+id+"' value='delete' onclick='delete_row("+id+");'/></td></tr>";
    document.getElementById("new_title").value="";
    document.getElementById("new_anonce").value="";
    document.getElementById("new_url").value="";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

PHP

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'rel_eq';
if ( isset( $_POST['edit_row'] ) ){
    $wpdb->update( $table_name, array(
        'id'=>$_POST['row_id'],
        'title' => $_POST['title_val'], 
        'anonce' => $_POST['anonce_val'],
        'url' => $_POST['url_val']),

    array( 'id' => $_POST['row_id'] ),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
    );
     echo mysql_insert_id();
     exit();
}

if ( isset( $_POST['insert_row'] ) ){
    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'id'=>$_POST['row_id'],
        'title' => $_POST['title_val'], 
        'anonce' => $_POST['anonce_val'],
        'url' => $_POST['url_val']),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
    );
     echo mysql_insert_id();
     exit();
}

if ( isset( $_POST['delete_row'] ) ){
    $wpdb->delete( $table_name, array(
        'id'=>$_POST['row_id']),
        array( '%s') 
    );
     echo mysql_insert_id();
     exit();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you checked the request data? Have you tried to dump anything?

Comment: there are no errors in the console

Comment: Have you checked to see if you're actucally getting a response from PHP ?
 Where is the PHP code that sends the response?

Comment: PHP gets the data and successfully writes to the database, JS code that I wrote in the idea is supposed to clean up the INPUT ???

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Have you checked to see if you're actually getting a response from PHP? Where is the PHP code that sends the response? In your code you **send** data to PHP, then PHP is supposed to send data back to your ajax. This is the `success:function(response)` part of your JS/AJAX

Comment: No, I do not check. how to do it?

Comment: Using the dev tools

Comment: Or by putting console.log in the success fn

Comment: 1. Are you sure you can get the id after receive the response   
2. I would suggest you use ```$('#row'+id).remove()``` to delete the row since you already load jQuery.